# Trying To Program A Data Sorting Program with Pointers Arrays and Bubble Sort PLEASE ASSIST

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, bubble-sort

I am unsure of what to do next as these errors make no sense to me maybe I am doing something wrong which someone else can see. This has all the correct structure just I have wrong syntax. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code and this is how far I have gotten and when I try to compile I get these errors:

```
gcc Pointers.c

Pointers.c:14: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘array’
Pointers.c:32: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘array’
Pointers.c:44: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘array’
Pointers.c:56: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘array’
Pointers.c:78: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘pointer’
Pointers.c: In function ‘main’:
Pointers.c:102: error: ‘array’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Pointers.c:102: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
Pointers.c:102: error: for each function it appears in.)
Pointers.c:104: error: ‘pointer’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Here is the assignment page :
http://www.cs.miami.edu/~wuchtys/CSC322-13F/Assessment/LT5.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE_OF_ARRAY 5

//=============================================================================

    int *IntegerPtr;
    int  ArrayInt[SIZE_OF_ARRAY]; 
    int *ArrayPtr[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
/* Initializes the elements of an array of five integers to random integers 
 Initializes the elements of an array of five pointers to integers to point to the corresponding elements of the array of integers. */

void ArrayInitialize(ArrayInt array,ArrayPtr pointer){

  int i;
  srand(getpid());

  for (i =0, int < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++){

    array[i] = (int)rand()

  for (i =0, int < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++){

        pointer[i] = &array[i];
                                      }
                      }
    }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*Have a function that prints an array of five integers*/

void ArrayPrint(ArrayInt array){
 int i;

   for (i =0, int < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++){
    printf("%d : %10d \n",i,array[i]);

 }
printf("\n");
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*Have a function that prints the integers pointed to by an array of five pointers to                                        integers.*/

void ArrayPointerPrint(ArrayInt array){
 int i;

   for (i =0, int < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++){
    printf("%d : %10d \n",i,pointer[i]);

 }
printf("\n");
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*Have a function that uses a bubble-sort to sort an array of five integers, in ascending order of the integers. */

void ArrayBubbleSort(ArrayInt array){

  int i;
  int j;
  int temp;

  for( i = (SIZE_OF_ARRAY - 1); i >= 0; i-- )
  {
    for( j = 1; j <= i; j++ )
    {
      if( *(array+(j-1)) > *(array+j))
      {
         temp = *array+(j-1));
        *array+(j-1)) = array+(j));
        *array+(j) = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*Have a function that uses a bubble-sort to sort an array of five pointers to integers */
 void PointerBubbleSort(ArrayPtr pointer){

  int i;
  int j;
  int temp;

  for( i = (SIZE_OF_ARRAY - 1); i >= 0; i-- )
  {
    for( j = 1; j <= i; j++ )
    {
      if( *(pointer+(j-1)) > *(pointer+j))
      {
        temp = *pointer+(j-1));
        *pointer+(j-1)) = pointer+(j));
        *pointer+(j) = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

 int main(void) {

    array[SIZE_OF_ARRAY]; 

    pointer[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];

    ArrayInitialize(array,pointer);

    ArrayPrint(array);

    PointerBubbleSort(pointer);

    ArrayPointerPrint(pointer);

    ArrayBubbleSort(array);

    ArrayPrint(array);

    ArrayPointerPrint(pointer);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

These are variables:

```
int *IntegerPtr;
int  ArrayInt[SIZE_OF_ARRAY]; 
int *ArrayPtr[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
```

Your code is using them like typedefs.

Perhaps instead of this

```
void ArrayInitialize(ArrayInt array,ArrayPtr pointer){
```

You want to use

```
void ArrayInitialize(int *array,int *pointer){
```

In all your code, try subsituting `ArrayInt` and `ArrayPointer` with `int *` and I think it will 
compile.

And then change

```
array[SIZE_OF_ARRAY]; 
pointer[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
```

to

```
int array[SIZE_OF_ARRAY]; 
int pointer[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
```

Comment: Remove them and do the subsitution I suggested.

Comment: Ok, well that's progress. Study what the compiler is trying to tell you and if you can't figure it out ask another question. Good luck.